# Row Separators are missing for Grid

Tags: jqgrid

I have the same post at http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/discussion/missing-row-seperator/&value=4475&type=9&include=0&search=1&ret=all, just post here again as I had been have good luck getting responses.

Hello, I just started playing with jqGrid today. I copied and pasted some samples from the demo site, but found my grid does not have the row seperator (the lines between the rows) rendered. What did I do wrong?
Following is referenced in my html file:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
```

and I am using jqGrid 3.8.2

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question. I fixed it by adding reference to grid.locale-en.js

Answer (score 0):

It is possible some CSS definition on the page is removing the lines. Use a tool (like the IE or Chrome built in one) to see the styles that apply to the table cells or rows.